# cx_Oracle does not work with Oracle database 10gR2

Tags: python, oracle, oracle10g, instantclient

using python3.6 I have installed cx_Oracle 6.4.1 and the instantclient for **Oracle 10gR2** (basic-10.2.0.5.0-linux-x64) but it doesn't work. 
In previous releases of cx_Oracle it used to connect with 10gR2 databases but now it seems not to be supported anymore.

Is there a way in python to connect to this version of database?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify, you should still be able to connect to 10g **databases**, but the current version only supports 12.2, 12.1 and 11.2 **clients**. The 11.2 client works with Oracle database 9.2 and up.

Comment: Thanks you for the answer! Can I Aldo connect through the 12.1 client?

Comment: Probably. Why not try it?

Answer (score 0):

From the [cx_Oracle installation instructions](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html):

> Oracle client libraries versions 12.2, 12.1 and 11.2 are supported

From the [cx_Oracle installation instructions on interoperability](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability):

> Oracle’s standard client-server network interoperability allows
>   connections between different versions of Oracle Client libraries and
>   Oracle Database. For certified configurations see Oracle Support’s Doc
>   ID 207303.1. In summary, Oracle Client 12.2 can connect to Oracle
>   Database 11.2 or greater. Oracle Client 12.1 can connect to Oracle
>   Database 10.2 or greater. Oracle Client 11.2 can connect to Oracle
>   Database 9.2 or greater. The technical restrictions on creating
>   connections may be more flexible. For example Oracle Client 12.2 can
>   successfully connect to Oracle Database 10.2.

Your quick solution is to install the 12.1 or 12.2 Instant Client RPMs.  (The longer solution is to upgrade your DB to a supported release!)